# ¿Cómo puedo validar arrays con expReg en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hola estoy intentando hacer este script, pero no se como enfocarlo para que vaya recorriendo los elementos y diga lo siguiente :

Crear un script que obtenga una lista de palabras tecleadas por el usuario
y los almacene en un array hasta que el usuario introduzca la cadena vacía.
Validaremos utilizando una expresión regular que las palabras introducidas tienen al menos 2
letras mayúsculas en cualquier posición,informando del error en caso contrario.
Escribe en la página la siguiente información:

1. La primera palabra introducida por el usuario.
2. La última palabra introducida por el usuario.
3. La palabra de mayor longitud introducida por el usuario.
4. La media aritmética de las longitudes de la palabras, redondeada al
   entero menor...

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
                        frases = new Array();
                        var frase = "";
                        var indiceMayor = 0;
                        var media = 0;
                        let regEx = new RegExp(/^.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*$/);
                        do {
                            frase = prompt("Introduzca la frase");
                            if (frase && regEx.test(frase)) {
                                frases.push(frase);
                                media += frase.length;
                                if (frases[indiceMayor].length < frase.length) {
                                    indiceMayor = frases.length - 1;
                                }
                            } else if (frase && !regEx.test(frase)) {
                                alert("Tiene que tener al menos dos mayusculas");
                            }
                        } while (frase)
                        document.write(frases[0] + "<br>")
                        document.write(frases[frases.length - 1] + "<br>")
                        document.write(frases[indiceMayor] + "<br>")
                        media = media / frases.length
                        document.write("La media es " + media);
                    </script>
```

Ejercicio resuelto gracias a todos.

Comment: ¿Nos muestras que has intentado hasta le momento?, checa [ask]

Comment: Está el código arriba, estaba intentando dejar limpio el cógido un saludo eso es lo que tengo hasta el momento, gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Para validar que cada string del array tenga al menos 2 letras mayúsculas en cualquier posición mediante expresiones regulares, lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```js
let lista_de_palabras = ["PruebA", "Prueba", "prueba"]; // Tu arreglo de palabras

lista_de_palabras.forEach(palabra => {
   if (!palabra.match(".*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*")) {
      console.log("Error en palabra: " + palabra);
   }
});
```

La expresión regular ".*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*" la saqué de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18714367/8179980)